# accelerated charged particles and interaction with magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

In high school we are taught that magnetic field perpendicular to velocity of an charged particle experience perpendicular force that causes it to move in circular path by relation
$$qvB=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$ but in drawbacks of Bohr's theory it was proposed that accelerated charged electron orbiting along nucleus will immediately loose energy in form of electromagnetic waves and collapse into nucleus.So My question basically is are we taught wrong about this relation that charged particle according to Lorenz's force will perform circular motion as far as required conditions in equations are provided but will it eventually loose energy in form of electromagnetic radiation and halt it's circular orbit ?

Comment: please tell me the answer and not just edit it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accelerated charged particles emit electromagnetic radiation. In this case, where the acceleration is caused by a magnetic field and is perpendicular to the velocity, the radiation is called [cyclotron radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_radiation). Since the magnetic field doesn't work on (electrically) charged particles, the radius of the charged particle should reduce, as it's energy (and so it's speed) reduces due to the radiation.

Comment: Thanks a lot that means my physics problem book is a big lie beause it has several questions directly based on lorenz's force and ubiform circular motion

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the charged particle is accelerated, it will emit radiation. But it never stops at a point because of the uncertainty principle. Refer [Energy of electron spinning in a magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71976/energy-of-electron-spinning-in-a-magnetic-field)